# Who took the money in No Country for Old Men?

Tags: plot-explanation, no-country-for-old-men

I just watched *No Country for Old Men* and my question is do we know for sure that when Moss was killed, those Mexican killers took the money, if not who did?

Also Anton's assignment was to get the money, was it given to him by the same guys who finally took the money from Moss's room and if they did then it means Anton failed his task and the unseen ringleader whoever hired him must be really angry on him?

P.S.- I just read somewhere that Anton had the money at end, but clearly the satchel is not shown when he gets out of the car after accident? He just took one dollar bill (possibly 100 dollars) out from under his shirt and that could be from his pocket?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In No Country for Old Men, who does Anton Chigurh work for (Why did he kill them?)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24837/in-no-country-for-old-men-who-does-anton-chigurh-work-for-why-did-he-kill-them)

Comment: *"Finally, when I was reading about the book that inspired the movie, it mentions that **Chigurh returns the money** towards the end"*

Comment: But the movie doesnot answer where that satchel is?

Comment: No...but that's not really important...the characters are.

Comment: The clue that Anton eventually found the money is the scene where he offers the kid the $100 bill for the shirt. The satchel was filled with $100 bills.

Comment: However it’s not clear where Moss hid the money or how Anton found it.  When Bell noticed the register removed from the ductwork in the last motel room, it’s clear that the duct is too small for the satchel to have been hidden there. It’s also clear that Anton hasn’t found the satchel because he’s still in the room shown hiding behind the door. We know he’s still there because when Bell inspects the bathroom, there is a scene showing the lock on the window sash and the lock is closed. This strongly suggests that Sheriff Bell is another victim and eventually dies in that room (+dream sequences)

Answer (score 10):

The scene where he has the car accident is not immediately after **Lewelln**  was killed.  It was much later.  I suspect it could have been days or weeks after.  **Chigurh** was the type of person who would not let the wife live but wasn't in a rush to kill her.

The car accident comes immediately after he leaves her house.  But the money was likely recovered by him days or weeks before (once the crime scene had been closed up by the cops).

I think he got the money, not the **Mexicans**.  The Mexicans didn't know Lewelln's trick of hiding the bag in the a/c vent and didn't have time to look for it with all the commotion they caused with the gun fight with Lewelln.

Chigurh got the money later.  So after the crime scene had been closed up he went to the room, popped the lock, found the bag and was in the process of leaving when Bell shows up the second time.

I'm still a bit uncertain where he was hiding but he was clearly near-by as you saw him in the shadows.  But for whatever reason he did not confront Bell.

Comment: never thought about this angle.

Comment: Completely agree with this interpretation and the film provides the clues as well. When Sheriff Bell is sitting in the hotel after Chigurh has left you can see that the vent cover has been removed using a dime to remove the screws, just as was done in the previous hotel, indicating that Chigurh checked the vent and found the money.

Answer (score 0):

The clue that Anton eventually found the money is the scene where he offers the kid the $100 bill for the shirt. The satchel was filled with $100 bills.

However it’s not clear where Moss hid the money or how Anton found it. When Bell noticed the register removed from the ductwork in the last motel room, it’s clear that the duct is too small for the satchel to have been hidden there. It’s also clear that Anton hasn’t found the satchel because he’s still in the room shown hiding behind the door. We know he’s still there because when Bell inspects the bathroom, there is a scene showing the lock on the window sash and the lock is closed. This strongly suggests that Sheriff Bell is about to become another victim of Anton’s. The final scenes with Bell are certainly somewhat surreal and may represent his thoughts as he’s dying.

Answer (score -3):

As guessed by the Belarusian reviewer "ЧБУ", Anton Chigurh *did not exist at all*.

It is just an image of a deadly all-powerful silent killer how the Sheriff imagines him based on his own (aging) perception of crimes. The Sheriff admits he does not understand crime these days at all, and the Sheriff (not Moss) is actually the main hero of the story.

In view of this, the Mexicans took the money.

Source:

(English subtitles)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  This is quite the bold theory; do you have any evidence to support it?  (That would include alternate explanations for how all the actions ascribed to Chigurh would have taken place without him.)

Comment: Hey David, this is not my theory but the author of the video above. I did watch the video and I think he is very convincing. He does explain the rest of actions and other assumptions, but moreover the movie started making more sense to me after it. There are English subtitles, you can see it for yourself.

Comment: If he didn't exist then who shot all those people?